# Implement delayed queue with RxJs Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

<del>Imagine we have a queue of booleans (we don't need a complex datastructure since we wanna store only the fact of the order). Items can get into the queue at anytime in any pace. The Observable would pop items from this queue and emit them in a delayed manner but the first emit is not needed to be delayed. After the queue gets empty it stay on hold until a new item gets in the queue which it will emmit right away. Please help me implement this behaviour.</del>

Given a user can press a button which increments a counter. At start the counter is on 0 and the user clicks two times in 500 ms. The first click increments the counter to one but the second click will take action delayed by 500 ms. The user then waits more than 500 ms and clicks. The third click has to increment the counter right away since there is no other increment action in progress so to say. If the third click happens in the 500 ms window then it has to wait till the other finishes.

Yeah, I think I get your problem @estus. Somehow it would be neccessary to register where is the last action in its progress. Saving the time when it was emitted or something.

Given the first click has happened 300ms before and a new click happens. In this case the 2nd click has to wait only 200ms.
[image]

**Update1:**
[Here](http://jsbin.com/mulocegalu/1/edit?html,js,output) is the code based on Dorus's answer

Comment: These are two different cases. Posting the existing code would help to get an answer that suits your case (if there is any).

Comment: There is no code yet. I'm about to implement something in jsbin using Dorus's answer. The observable is like a guardian. It does not let others go through until the passenger has left the bufferzone aka. got far away enough from the gate. If there is noone in the buffer zone then the next passenger can go through right away. That's what I need to implement in an observable manner.

Comment: For the first case, please, specify which input you expect and which output (with ms timeline), because the description isn't specific enough. Again, the second case is not just an example but a different case, and it is't clear what should happen with 3rd click in 500ms window. If your question requires recipes for *both* cases then please, state this explicitly.

Comment: Passengers are analogous to user clicks so the queue is not a must have I just thought it is easier to explain/implement that way.

Comment: The thing you're describing is pretty close to generic throttle/debounce. I cannot be sure but possibly [`throttleTime` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime) does exactly what you want.

Comment: Does throttleTime keep every click?

Comment: No, it ignores every click but the first and the last within time window. Do you need to keep them? [Drawing a diagram](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc/designguidelines#41-consider-drawing-a-marble-diagram) for input and output would be really helpful here (ASCII `--1---2--` art would be fine).

Comment: Yeah, I need to keep them. I thought of the diagram too, but got confused how to represent the idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap):

```
delay = 1000; // delay in ms
queue.concatMap(e =>
    Rx.Observable.of(e) // emit first item right away
      .concat(Rx.Observable.empty().delay(delay)) // delay next item
  )
```

Comment: Amazing! Brilliant!

Comment: FYI. I had to change the code a bit to avoid an error:
`Rx.Observable.empty().delay(delay)`

Comment: @apreg Oops correct, i fixed my answer for others :)